# Javascript remoting: to invokeAction or not to invokeAction

Tags: visualforce, javascript-remoting

Digging in deeper to Javascript Remoting and I'm a bit confused.  The [Salesforce Documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#CSHID=pages_js_remoting_example.htm%7CStartTopic=Content%2Fpages_js_remoting_example.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp) starts off by showing how to set up everything and uses code like the following:

```
function getRemoteAccount() {
    var accountName = document.getElementById('acctSearch').value;

    // This remoting call will use the page's timeout value
    Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
        '{!$RemoteAction.AccountRemoter.getAccount}',
        accountName, 
        handleResult
    );
}
```

However, I've also seen examples where Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction is never called.  They end up looking something like the following:

```
function getText() {
  var text = "";
  JSRemotingBasicsController.doGetText(
    function(result, event) {
      // do something here
    }
  );
}
```

I'm wondering what is the point to using `Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction` when you can just reference the RemoteAction directly like the second example?  Is there something I'm missing?  Is there a time where the second example doesn't work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main difference that I know of is that the `invokeAction` call will automatically resolve namespaces for you.

For example, if your remote method is in a class within a namespace the second method would have to be called as follows:

```
namespace.controller.method(
    [parameters...,]
    callbackFunction,
    [configuration]
);
```

When using `Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction` you can use `$RemoteAction` to automatically resolve the namespace and give you the fully qualified remote action name.

So the example above would become the following (notice the namespace is omitted):

```
Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
    '{!$RemoteAction.controller.method}', 
    [parameters...,]
    callbackFunction,
    [configuration]
);
```

One thing to keep in mind with this method is that if `$RemoteAction` finds matching
`@RemoteAction` methods in multiple namespaces, it returns the **first** matching method and logs a warning to the JavaScript console.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my initial thought of not too much difference.  Namespaces could be an issue, but I prefer to be more explicit than implicit in those cases anyway.